# Getting subscription payment history from Apple in-app purchase receipt

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to pull historical payments per-subscription from Apple, and I've run into some problems. What I'm hoping for is something similar to what I get from Stripe, where I send a subscription ID and receive an array of transactions (including payment date, payment amount, discount, currency, etc.).

Using in-app subscription purchases from React Native, the app receives and store what appear to be "iOS 6 style" receipts (regardless of the actual iOS version).

Validating these with Apple on a regular basis has worked well in order to check the current subscription status, but Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1) suggests that the only way to retrieve historical transactions is to provide an "iOS 7 style" receipt. Even then, the returned receipt objects [do not appear](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW12) to contain information about the amount paid, the currency they were paid in, and whether Apple's cut was 15% or 30%.

First question would be how (or even if) I can transform the "iOS 6 style" receipt into "iOS 7 style" - or whether there's another way to get full history for a given subscription ID? The second would be how to retrieve the actual transaction information, above and beyond a simple "payment of some kind happened at this time"?

Answer (score 2):

To be able to fetch data of user's transactions you need a receipt. Using [apple verifyReceipt api](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1) you'll able to get all needed information, except prices.

I not sure, but there is no way to convert iOS6 style receipt into iOS7 style. But, I hope it may be done on client-side (device) automatically.

If you just want to get financial information look at [Apple Reporter Tool](http://help.apple.com/itc/contentreporterguide/en.lproj/static.html), which allow you to fetch any financial data you want (subscriptions, inapps, application installs, applciations purchases).